# Audio volume control using the mergExt mergAV external

Tags: audio, livecode

How do I control the audio volume of an A/V player created by the LiveCode mergExt suite's mergAV external? I need to turn the player's audio on and off, as well as set its volume to a specific value (0 - 100).

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible so would need to be added to mergAV. Unfortunately Apple decided not to give AVPlayer an volume or mute property which is why it's not yet implemented. There is a workaround though. There is also MPVolumeView which could be added to mergMP which presents the system volume control.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Monte. It seems odd that you can't directly control the volume using LiveCode. Oh well, I can wait until MPVolumeView is added to mergMP  ;)   And, thanks for mergExt - it's been a life-saver!